# Asp.Net Core Tag Helpers not available in Sub-Directory

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

According to the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html#managing-tag-helper-scope):

> The `@addTagHelper` directive makes Tag Helpers available to the view. In this case, the view file is `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`, which by default is inherited by all view files in the Views folder and sub-directories; making Tag Helpers available.

So I imported the Tag Helpers in the `Views\_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using MyProject
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

and they work well on files inside the `Views` folder.

However, in the file `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, I don't have support for Tag Helpers, neither are they correctly rendered as links. When I copy the `_ViewImports.cshtml` into the folder `Views/Home`, everything works as expected.

So what am I missing?

**Update**

So what am I missing? That my `_ViewImports.cshtml` was put in the folder `Views/Shared` (d'oh). After moving it to `Views`, the TagHelpers work as intended everywhere.

Comment: It works for me. If you have created your own taghelper then you have to create entry for that in _ViewImports.cshtml file.

Comment: I want to use the helpers defined by Microsoft, namely `asp-controller` and `asp-action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a blank new ASP.NET Core 1.0 project and add it is working fine under `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view. This is what you have to do (Make sure that it is available):

Add to following package and tool section into your `project.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
  }  
},
```

and

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
```

Create an `_ViewImports.cshtml` file under Views folder (You have one already) with the contents that you have mentioned.

**Note: You may have to restart your VS to get it working.**

Comment: Yes, it works for me when I put the file in the right folder (see update to my question). Thanks!